# How to allow easy overriding of default options in a javascript function?

Tags: javascript, array-merge

I am writing the following function in javascript:

```
Number.prototype.niceFormat(options) {
    var defaultOptions = {
        thousandSeparator: ',',
        leftPad: 0,
        decimalPlaces: 2
    };
    if (typeof options.thousandSeparator != 'undefined'
    && options.thousandSeparator != null) {
        defaultOptions.thousandSeparator = options.thousandSeparator;
    }

}
```

The troublesome thing is I want options to be entirely flexible.

if I call the `niceFormat({decimalPlaces: 3})`, then the `defaultOptions` property `decimalPlaces` is replaced accordingly.

I would hate to write the if statement as many times as there are properties in the `defaultOptions`.

Is there a nice way to flexibly overwrite the value of the properties in `defaultOptions`?

Basically I am looking for a sort of `array_merge` for objects in javascript.

UPDATE:

I took the answers from Qantas and Crayon and Paul comment and wrote this:

```
Number.prototype.niceFormat = function(options) {
    var defaultOptions = {
        thousandSeparator: ',',
        leftPad: 0,
        decimalPlaces: 2
    };

    var env = defaultOptions;
    if (typeof options != 'undefined') {
        for (option in env) {
            if (options.hasOwnProperty(option)
            && typeof options[option] != 'undefined') {
                    env[option] = options[option];
            }
        }
    }
```

Anyway to improve this further?

Comment: using `options.option` will look for a property of `options` called `option`, not the value of `option`.  You need to use `options[option]`

Comment: made about 5 different edits before nailing down this version. Is this okay?

Comment: As `defaultOptions` is within the _function_, apply properties from `options` to `defaultOptions`, then use `defaultOptions` when checking properties later. If `defaultOptions` is shared, create a new empty _Object_ in the _function_, `var env = {}`, copy over `defaultOptions` then copy over `options`, then use `env`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is check both contain that property, then assign to it:

```
for (var i in options) if (options.hasOwnProperty(i) && defaultOptions.hasOwnProperty(i)) defaultOptions[i] = options[i];
```

`hasOwnProperty()` checks that the property is directly on that object (not through any prototype or something) and that it actually exists on the object.

Answer (score 1):

```
for (option in defaultOptions) {
  if (typeof options[option]=='undefined') options[option] = defaultOptions[option];
}
```